# How to use `ssl_crl` conditionally for specific CA?

Tags: nginx, ssl, tls1.2, nginx-config

I am trying to tryin to use the directive `ssl_crl` conditionally. I want to use the `ssl_crl` only for specific client CA. For other CAs, I do not want to use the CRL.

One approach I tried was to set nginx variable using client issuer and use the variable with `ssl_crl`.

So I added this to the `http` block

```
map $ssl_client_i_dn $ssl_crl_value {
    default    off;
    "specific CA"   "specific_ca_crl.pem";
};
```

And then following in the `server` block.

```
ssl_crl $ssl_crl_value;
```

With that, NGINX assumes `$ssl_crl_value` is a filename and tries to open `/etc/nginx/$ssl_crl_value` without variable expansion (`/etc/nginx/specific_ca_crl.pem`).

In the NGINX [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_crl), there is no explicit mention of whether `ssl_crl` supports variable or not (There is a [special note](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) for `ssl_certificate`). Does that mean `ssl_crl` does not support variables? Is there any other way to implement conditional behavior for `ssl_crl`?